# Bukari Hadith Reference

Tags: hadith, source-identification, sahih-bukhari, prophet-adam

I have come by the given hadith many times like Ibn Kathir Story of the Prophets books and well as many other places. I'm looking for the exact reference in Sahih Bukhari but not finding it. Can someone help me ? The Hadith is:

> Abu Hurayrah narrated that the Prophet Muhammad sallallahu 'alayhi wa
>   sallam said: "Allah created Adam from dust after He mixed the clay and
>   left him for some time until it became sticky mud, after which Allah
>   shaped him. After that Allah left him till it became like potter's
>   clay. Iblis used to go past him saying 'You have been created for a
>   great purpose.' After that Allah breathed His spirit into him. The
>   first thing into which the spirit passed was his eye and then his
>   nose. He sneezed. Allah said: 'May your Lord have mercy upon you, O
>   Adam! Go to those angels and see what they would say.' So Adam went
>   and greeted them, they replied saying: 'Peace be upon you and the
>   mercy and blessings of Allah.' Allah said: 'O Adam! This is your
>   greeting and that of your offspring.' " [Sahih al-Bukhari]

You can find the hadith in the following places:

- http://sunnahonline.com/library/stories-of-the-prophets/288-story-of-adam-the
- http://www.sikhsangat.com/index.php?/topic/59292-does-this-mean-sikhs-also-believe-in-existence-of-adam-and-eve/
- http://www.a2youth.com/ebooks/stories_of_the_prophets/the_story_of_adam_and_eve_hawwa/2

Comment: May I ask where did you get this hadith text from?

Comment: I mentioned the sources in the link in my question, also, the very same hadith is mentioned in Ibn Kathir, story of the prophet books, page 6, last paragraph, http://www.islamguiden.com/arkiv/stories_of_the_prophets.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The ahadith narrated by abu Hurraira on the matter and which at least seem to go ahead with parts of your quote are the two similar (or identical ahadith) from sahih al-Bukhari quoted in Chapter: [How the Salam began](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/79/1) and Chapter: [The creation of Adam and his offspring](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/60/1).

The longer version of the hadith you quoted as far as i can tell isn't in sahih al-Bukahri itself, but i could find in [fath al-Barry](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?idfrom=6052&idto=6071&bk_no=52&ID=2031) of ibn Hajar al-'Asqalani as a commentary on the narrations of Imam al-Bukhari in the Chapter: The creation of Adam and his offspring, saying that al-Bukhari has quoted a lot of ahadith on the subject but didn't mention some others and began to quot them.

> ومما لم يذكره ما رواه الترمذي والنسائي والبزار وصححه **ابن حبان** من طريق **سعيد المقبري** وغيره عن أبي هريرة مرفوعا

Ibn Hajar said this hadith was qualified as sahih by **ibn Hebban ابن حبان** . So according ibn Hajar this hadith was narrated by at-Tirmidhi, an-Nasai, al-Bazzar and ibn Hebban (via **Said al-Maqbary سعيد المقبري**). I found [this](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=87&bookhad=13900) version from majma' az-zwaaid of al-Haythami where the hadith isn't marfo' and has some additions and a rawy called Imsa'il ibn Rafi' which is qualified as trustworthy by al-Bukhari while the majority of scholars disagree!

There are also parts of other ahadith which may "support" the authenticity of your Version:

- on the authority of Anas in Sahih [Muslim](http://sunnah.com/muslim/45/146) and Musnad Ahmad.
- on the authority of abu Musa al-Ash'ary in sunan [abi Dawod](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/42/98) and Jami' [at-Tirmdihi](http://sunnah.com/urn/739390).

See also what ibn Kathir has quoted in [al-Bidya wa-nihaya](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?idfrom=16&idto=16&bk_no=59&ID=21) (in Arabic).

**Conclusion:** this hadith isn't a part of the ahadith quoted by al-Bukhari on the creation of Adam, but can be found in the commentary of ibn Hajar al-'Asqalani on them.

---

**Analysis of your references:**

- Reference 1 & 3 are IMO the same they pretend being a translation of qasas al-Anbiya' (stories of the Prophets) of Imam ibn Kathir. As i don't have a hardcopy or any other source to check that, i just made a comparison between the text of what is called a translation by  Muhammad Mustapha Geme’ah from Al-Azhar and [this "copy"](https://ar.wikisource.org/wiki/%D9%82%D8%B5%D8%B5_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D9%86%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%A1_%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%A8%D9%86_%D9%83%D8%AB%D9%8A%D8%B1/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AC%D8%B2%D8%A1_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D9%88%D9%84#.D8.A8.D8.A7.D8.A8:_.D9.85.D8.A7_.D9.88.D8.B1.D8.AF_.D9.81.D9.8A_.D8.AE.D9.84.D9.82_.D8.A2.D8.AF.D9.85_.D8.B9.D9.84.D9.8A.D9.87_.D8.A7.D9.84.D8.B3.D9.84.D8.A7.D9.85) of the original Arabic text. And I couldn't find this hadith as is there and not even in the same chapter (even the chapter titles of the translation differ). Ibn Kathir quoted the ahadith from both sahih books and the above quoted version of sahih ibn Hebban (and he said that this is a narration compiled by abu Hathim أبو حاتم and ibn Hebban in his sahih) and a version of the hafidh abu Ya'la أبو يعلى, so the referencing in those two texts is wrong. Note that the version of ibn Hebban is more than a bit different. Here the "original" texts from  قصص الأنبياء لابن كثير (In bold letters you may find names of the authors of the hadith compilation the route al-Maqbary and the parts which are similar or identic to your quoted hadith):

  > وقد **رواه أبو حاتم وابن حبان** في "صحيحه" فقال: حدثنا محمد بن إسحاق بن خزيمة، حدثنا محمد بن بشار، حدثنا صفوان بن عيسى، حدثنا الحارث بن عبد الرحمن بن أبي ذباب، عن **سعيد المقبري**، عن أبي هريرة قال: قال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم : "**لما خلق الله آدم ونفخ فيه الروح عطس، فقال الحمد لله. فحمد الله بإذن الله، فقال له ربه: يرحمك ربك يا آدم، اذهب إلى أولئك الملائكة إلى ملأ منهم جلوس فسلم عليهم ، فقال: السلام عليكم، فقالوا وعليكم السلام ورحمة الله. ثم رجع إلى ربه فقال هذه تحيتك وتحية بنيك بينهم**. وقال الله ويداه مقبوضتان: اختر أيهما شئت، فقال اخترت يمين ربي وكلتا يدي ربي يمين مباركة، ثم بسطهما فإذا فيهما آدم وذريته، فقال: أي رب ما هؤلاء؟ قال هؤلاء ذريتك، وإذا كل إنسان منهم مكتوب عمره بين عينيه، وإذا فيهم رجل أضوؤهم - أو من أضوئهم - لم يكتب له إلا أربعون سنة، قال: يا رب من هذا؟ قال: هذا ابنك **داود**. وقد كتب الله عمره أربعين سنة. قال: أي رب زد في عمره، فقال ذاك الذي كتب له، قال: فإني قد جعلت له من عمري ستين سنة، قال: أنت وذاك. اسكن الجنة. فسكن الجنة ما شاء الله ثم هبط منها، وكان آدم يعد لنفسه. فأتاه ملك الموت فقال له آدم: قد عجلت، قد كتب لي ألف سنة. قال: بلى، ولكنك جعلت لابنك **داود** منها ستين سنة، فجحد آدم فجحدت ذريته، ونسي فنسيت ذريته، فيومئذ أمر بالكتاب والشهود" هذا لفظه.
  >
  > وقال **الحافظ أبو يعلى**: حدثنا عقبة بن مكرم، حدثنا عمرو بن محمد، عن إسماعيل بن رافع، **عن المقبري**، عن أبي هريرة، أن رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم قال: **"إن الله خلق آدم من تراب، ثم جعله طينا ثم تركه، حتى إذا كان حمأ مسنون خلقه الله وصوره ثم تركه، حتى إذا كان صلصالا كالفخار قال: فكان إبليس يمر به فيقول: لقد خلقت لأمر عظيم.
  >
  >   ثم نفخ الله فيه من روحه فكان أول ما جرى فيه الروح بصره وخياشيمه، فعطس فلقاه الله رحمة به، فقال الله! يرحمك ربك، ثم قال الله: يا آدم اذهب إلى هؤلاء النفر فقل لهم فانظر ماذا يقولون؟ فجاء فسلم عليهم فقالوا: وعليك السلام ورحمة الله وبركاته. فقال: يا آدم هذا تحيتك وتحية ذريتك**. قال يا رب: وما ذريتي؟ قال: اختر "احدى" يدي يا آدم، قال: أختار يمين ربي وكلتا يدي ربي يمين، فبسط كفه فإذا من هو كائن من ذريته في كف الرحمن، فإذا رجال منهم أفواههم النور، وإذا رجل يعجب آدم نوره، قال يا رب من هذا؟ قال ابنك **داود**، قال: يا رب فكم جعلت له من العمر؟ قال جعلت له ستين، قال: يا رب فأتم له من عمري حتى يكون له من العمر مائة سنة، ففعل الله ذلك، وأشهد على ذلك.
  >   فلما نفذ عمر آدم بعث الله ملك الموت، فقال آدم: أولم يبق من عمري أربعون سنة؟ قال له الملك: أولم تعطها ابنك **داود**؟ فجحد ذلك، فجحدت ذريته، ونسي فنسيت ذريته!".

Note that abu Ya'las version begins as the one you've quoted but ends by the story of Allah telling Adam about his children and offspring while the Version of ibn Hebban starts with Adam sneezing and also ends with Allah telling Adam about his children (especially Dawod داود whom Adam has given 40 of his years of live according the version fo abu Ya'la and 60 accoring ibn Hebban's version), so non of them are a one to one translation. And ibn Kathir as a hadith scholar never would say "abu Hurairah said:..." without telling his source first or analyzing sources later. Imam an-Nawawi did so in his Riyad as-Saliheen and 40 hadiths but he explained his reasons first. IMO the author of this translation has created a fully new text based on the summary of original book of ibn Kathir, for example he quoted only a handful of ahadith from it and the Quran verses without many details about the interpretation of the verses and discussion of ahadith and sources etc..

**Note** That as it seems to me -after a fast examination of the chapters and some content about Adam- the book called qasas al-Anbiya' is what we may call an extract of al-Bidaya wa an-Nihya of ibn Kathir, as it seems to be a one to one copy of the quotes of that book.

- In your 2nd reference the post in the thread about Adam being quoted by sikhs which is quoting the hadith refers to an article on wikipedia. The article on wikipedia is linking to the correct [hadith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam#cite_note-46) (one of the two you may find on top of my post)! So either the Wikipedia article has been edited and corrected or the post is totally misleading!

Comment: thank you, nice answer, then based on your answer, i would say that it erroneous to say that this is a hadith, because this is what is mentioned in many places

Comment: @user1774937 I updated my answer analyzing the references you gave in your Post! as I didn't want to translate too much i just put in bold letters some key words to give a hint about them being used in the Arabic text.